# Prove by induction! Very confused as to how to start inductive step.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n \geq 3$, there exists $n$ distinct positive integers $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ such that

$$
1 = \frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a_n}.
$$

Comment: Hint: $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{6} = 1, \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{42} = 1$, and use strong induction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that $\displaystyle \frac{1}{k} = \frac{1}{k + 1} + \frac{1}{k(k + 1)}$. So, just write the last reciprocal $\displaystyle \frac{1}{a_n}$ (or whichever term has the largest denominator) in terms of two new reciprocals.

Edit: To figure out how one may have gone about solving this, you can think about splitting up the term with the largest denominator, say $\displaystyle \frac{1}{a_n}$, in terms of two new reciprocals $\displaystyle \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y}$. Solving for $x$, we get $\displaystyle x = \frac{a_ny}{y - a_n}$. To make $x$ an integer, we set $y = a_n + 1$. This then gives $x = a_n(a_n + 1)$. These two choices of $x, y$ clearly give us new reciprocals because $x$ and $y$ are greater than all previous denominators.

Comment: Edit suggested: split the term with the max denominator to preserve distinctness of denominators

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Thanks, I've done that

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is similar to say: prove that following equation has integral solutions for any n:

$$\frac1{a_1}+\frac1{a_2}+\frac1{a_3}+\cdot\cdot\cdot+\frac1{a_n}=1$$

I show this by a simple example; generaly we star with fact that we must have $\frac1{a_1}\geqslant\frac1n$ or $a_1\leqslant n$.

1-n=3; for this we must have:

$\frac1{a_1}+\frac1{a_2}+\frac1{a_3}=1$

$\frac1{a_1}\geqslant\frac13$ or $a_1\leqslant3$. Let $a_1=2$ so we have:

$\frac1{a_2}+\frac1{a_3}=1-\frac12=\frac12$
So we need $\frac1{a_2}<\frac12$ or $a_2>2$ or $a_2\geqslant3$, let $a_2=3$ we get:

$\frac1{a_3}=1-(\frac12+\frac13)=\frac12-\frac13=\frac16$

Which gives $a_3=6$

Now we want to show that there also exists a solution for $n+1=3+1=4$. For this we must have:

$\frac1{a_1}+\frac1{a_2}+\frac1{a_3}+\frac1{a_4}=1$

With $a_1=2$ and $a_2=3$ we must have $\frac1{a_3}+\frac1{a_4}=1-(\frac12+\frac13)=\frac16$

Or $\frac1{a_3}\leqslant\frac16$ or $a_3>6$; let $a_3=7$ then we get:

$\frac1{a_4}=1-(\frac12+\frac13+\frac17)=\frac1{42}$

which gives $a_4=42$

We can continue this argument for n=5, 6, 7, ... and so on and show that if there exists a solution for n there also exist a solution for n+1.